# Most pythonic for selecting one entry from a list of dicts based on dict key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

So let's say I have AllData, a list of nested dicts (let's pretend there are thousands of entries) but I'm only looking for a single entry.

```
AllData = [
    { "EntryA" : {"A Key":"A Value"} },
    { "EntryB" : {"B Key":"B Value"} },
    { "EntryC" : {"C Key":"C Value"} }
]
```

Currently I'm just looping through it and breaking once I find the matching key.

```
MyKey = "EntryB"
FoundData = {}
for item in AllData:
    for key,data in item.items():
        if MyKey.lower() == key.lower():
            FoundData = data
            break
print(FoundData)
```

However, being a Python enthusiast I know there's a more elegant way to do this. I've struggled a bit with proper list comprehension techniques but I'm trying! Below is the best I've been able to come up with that gathers this data in a single line but I'm wondering if there is an even MORE elegant solution to this problem.

```
MyKey = "EntryB"    
FoundData = [x for x in AllData if str(list(x.items())[0][0]).lower() == MyKey.lower()][0][MyKey]
print(FoundData)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you're concerned with being Pythonic, you should consider changing some of those variable names (if you're not constrained by the style of an existing project, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.8+ you can combine assignment expression (`:=`) and `any()` (`any()` will break when you find first valid element):

```
AllData = [
    { "EntryA" : {"A Key":"A Value"} },
    { "EntryB" : {"B Key":"B Value"} },
    { "EntryC" : {"C Key":"C Value"} }
]

if any((found:=d) for d in AllData if "EntryB" in d):
    print(found)
```

Prints:

```
{'EntryB': {'B Key': 'B Value'}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Python 3.6 but I'm just now learning of the assignment expression from this post so I will be reading up on that post haste!

Comment: What is the point of using a list comprehension (or generator expression) for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a list comprehension is the appropriate way of doing this, since you only want the first match.

```py
all_data = [
    {"EntryA": {"A Key": "A Value"}},
    {"EntryB": {"B Key": "B Value"}},
    {"EntryC": {"C Key": "C Value"}}
]

targ_key = "EntryB"

found_data = None

for curr_dict in all_data:
    if found_data := curr_dict.get(targ_key):
        break

print(found_data)
```

I'm still not entirely sure if using an assignment expression here is worth it, it might make it more difficult to understand.

Here is a version without the assignment expression:

```py
all_data = [
    {"EntryA": {"A Key": "A Value"}},
    {"EntryB": {"B Key": "B Value"}},
    {"EntryC": {"C Key": "C Value"}}
]

targ_key = "EntryB"

found_data = None

for curr_dict in all_data:
    curr_data = curr_dict.get(targ_key)
    if curr_data is not None:
        found_data = curr_data
        break

print(found_data)
```

Comment: 1) I see what you mean about var names, will keep that in mind :)

2) I have never seen or at least comprehended the := assignment expression before now I have an entire day of reading to do because I really do not understand what is happening there. So thanks for that :P

Comment: @Auscoi See the edit, I added a solution without the assignment expression. Have you been able to think about the list comprehension issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter()`, depending on the contens of MyKey, it will look something as:

```
AllData = [
    { "EntryA" : {"A Key":"A Value"} },
    { "EntryB" : {"B Key":"B Value"} },
    { "EntryC" : {"C Key":"C Value"} }
]
MyKey = "EntryB"
found = list(filter(lambda x: MyKey in x.keys(), AllData))[0][MyKey]
print(found)
```

Comment: _You could use `filter()`_ which isn't very pythonic, and the fact that a lambda is necessary is likely an indication that `filter()` isn't the right choice here.